# Excel SUMIF - check if the criteria range contains a substring of a given cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel worksheet with a large number of sub-accounts and their balances, that have to be aggregated to their accounts, according to a list that maps subaccounts to accounts.
I believe I could use the SUMIF or SUMIFS worksheet functions.

This is the layout:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Z3z.png)

Column B lists subaccount numbers, and column D the balance for each. In cell `Q232`, it is shown that the first account aggregates the subaccounts `8002`, `8998`, and `8001`.

For example, if `Q232` contained the value `"8900;8901"`, the result in `R232` should become the sum of `D209` and `D210`, because `B209` and `B210` contain `8900` and `8901`.

For the future usability of the sheet, VBA is probably not an option. I attempted to use worksheet functions, e.g. in cell `R232`

```
=SUMIFS($D$1:$D$216;$B$1:$B$216;SEARCH($B$1:$B$216;Q232)=1)
```

But this is the wrong syntax. I also don't see how I can use `VLOOKUP`, because the range I want to search through (column `B`) contains only substrings of the subaccount lists (`Q232` and below), instead of the other way around.

Comment: `=SUMIFS($D$1:$D$216;$B$1:$B$216;"*" & Q232 & "*")` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I would suggest you try the formula `=SUM(SUMIF($B$1:$B$216,TEXTSPLIT(E232,,";"),$D$1:$D$216))`.

[image]